# car-part-like filtering system to use with Magento

Tags: magento, filter

I have a filtering problem that i don't really know yet how to tackle.

I’m trying to find the simplest way to do an auto-part-like filtering for a couple of products in a Magento store. There is about 10 products, but each one is compatible with a certain set of car brands/models/years with some overlap.

What would be the best way to set up a filtering system where a person would select (from a drop-down menu or something like that) their car manufacturer, model and year & the system would return back the products that are compatible with their car? (Either links to product or something similar.)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I’m stuck on this and don’t have the first clue on how to move forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question by tagging it with "filter" magento has layered navigation filters for that. You need to set up your attribute sets and parameters and later assign those parameters to your products

Comment: Well the problem is that there would be way to many filters for it. If i create a category for manufacturers, the layered navigation for each brand would be couple of pages high (containing all models, years and types of stereo) & if i would go 2 subcategories deep and create categories for both manufacturer and model, it would mean manually creating 300-500 categories. I'm trying to find out if there is a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: spending the time to find elegant solution would be spent more wisely if you actually configure it by using defaults I guess you managed to import all this stuff from csv by now